# Is there a standard pattern for updating android views?

Tags: android, view, design-patterns

I'm currently building an android application with quite a few different connected activities. In each activity I've got a private updateView() method to update all the textViews and stuff on that screen. This gets called in the onResume() method so that each time the activity comes to the front it's views will be updated.

Is this the right way to do things or is there a more standard pattern for keeping your views in sync with the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are doing this correctly. onResume would be the perfect time to update your views, I assume you are only updating if there is actually new data to be displayed?

If retrieving the data during the updateView method takes a long time then you should do it in an AsyncTask to avoid clogging the UI Thread which will make your app hang.

In fact any data retrieval like getting data from the web or reading from your apps database should be done in an AsyncTask. This is because even if your data retrieval seems to take milliseconds on your device it may conceivably take longer on another, less powerful device.